# Is there a VESC firmware implementation that runs on Arduino?

Tags: motor

I am looking to use an Arduino in a motor control application, and have found that the VESC^ project has done some good work in this. I would like to have some fine-grain control over the motor drive, but using the VESC foundation looks great.

Research so far on Arduino and VESC discusses using an Arduino to interface with VESC hardware, however I'd be more interested in having the VESC firmware running *on* the Arduino, with output driving a power stage.

Is there a reason why this is not possible? (where the most powerful Arduino being insufficient on processing, not enough memory, etc.)

^VESC is an open Electronic Speed Control infrastructure for motor control that in completeness includes hardware, firmware and parameterisation/control sotfware. [VESC Project website.](https://vesc-project.com)

Comment: It might help if you define VESC.

Comment: @PMF Description added.